# 1 Jenkins Job with 2 Jenkinsfiles (declarative pipeline)

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have 1 job with 2 declarative pipelines scripts, from 1 script I am calling another one

now I am getting this error message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one pipeline { ... } block can
> be executed in a single run.

```
stage('Loading app Deployment File') {
    steps {
        script {
           def util = load './abcd/Jenkinsfile.groovy'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you really want to trigger a downstream job.

Comment: no in 1 job i need to run 2 Jenkins files

Answer (score 0):

You cant use two pipeline scripts in a single job, i see two options

1. create another job and call it as a downstream job

`build job: "path/to/jenkins_job",parameters:([string(name:'', value:'')]), propagate: false, wait: true`

2. Call the file as a closure from your jenkins File

   ```
   stage('foo'){
    options {
        timeout(time: 5, unit: "MINUTES")
    }

    steps{
        script{
            script1.call(arg1, arg2)

        }
    }
   ```

   }

And configure script1.groovy as follows

script1.groovy

```
#!groovy

def call(arg1, arg2){
    try{
        <do something>
        return
    } catch (Exception){
        < something has failed >
    }

  // you can also add stages here

    stage('bar'){
      try{
          <do something>
          return
      } catch (Exception){
        < something has failed >
      } 
    }
}
```

A Point to note that, with this method all pipeline variables can be utilized as well.

Comment: No.1 won't work if you want to pass objects(e.g. custom classes) to the downstream job.

Comment: We can use SharedLibraries to load any custom vars or classes inside the downstream job or any job as long as the library is loaded: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/